# Using laravel to create postgres table with point column without postGIS extension

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am new to Laravel and postgres. I am using postGres without postGIS extension, postGres alone does allow a point type for columns even without postGIS, my migration in the larval fails and gives me this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined
>   object: 7 ERROR:  type "geography" does not exist at character 134
>   (SQL: create table "profiles" ("id" bigserial primary key not null,
>   "produc t" varchar(50) not null, "details" varchar(1000) not null,
>   "xy" geography(point, 4326) not null, "created_at" timestamp(0)
>   without time zone null, "updated_at" timestamp(0) without time zone
>   null))

my code for migration function is below

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('pgsql')->create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('product',50);
            $table->string('details',1000);
            $table->point('xy');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

xy column is meant to be a simple point type available in postgres, but it appears that laravel translates this into geography type which is available in postGIS and I do not need postGIS in my case.

Please advise how to create a point column in laravel without postGIS.

Thanks

Comment: use `DB::statement` within migration after schema like:

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE profiles MODIFY xy POINT');`

Comment: how can you alter a non existing table ? the table is not created because of error above.

Comment: I am also new to postgress(so might not be of any help) but if you create the table manually(via a tool like DataGrip or HeidiSql), can you then see the `create table` scheme to see the creation code and verify what it should be? Could make searching for a solution easier I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
I was having same issue with Laravel Migration to create data type point for this  you can use Extended version of PostgresGrammar with support of 'point' data type in Postgres
```

[Write Laravel Migration to create postgres table column with data type point for to store latitude longitude (coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311845/write-laravel-migration-to-create-postgres-table-column-with-data-type-point-for/66311846#66311846)

```
    <?php
            namespace App\PosGress;
    
            use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar;
            use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
    
            /**
            * Extended version of PostgresGrammar with
            * support of 'point' data type in Postgres.
            */
            class ExtendedPostgresGrammar extends PostgresGrammar
            {
    
                /**
                * Create the column definition for a spatial Point type.
                *
                * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
                * @return string
                */
                protected function typePoint(Fluent $column)
                {
                return "$column->type";
                }
    
        }
    ?>
    Laravel Migration will be 
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use App\PosGress\ExtendedPostgresGrammar;
    
    class UpdateTableAddressesAddColumnPoints extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            // register new grammar class
            DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new ExtendedPostgresGrammar());
            $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
            $schema->table('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->point('geo_location')->nullable(); 
               
             });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */`enter code here`
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('geo_location');
            });
        }
    }
```